# Why ReactHighcharts SolidGauge's rounded is not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I use **react-highcharts** to create a SolidGauge in my Dashboard Page.

and draw rounded edges.

So , I setting the plotOptions.rounded to true.

code:

```
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts-more';
import SolidGauge from 'highcharts-solid-gauge';

HighchartsMore(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
SolidGauge(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);

...
<ReactHighcharts config={ config }/>

config = {
  ...
  plotOptions: { 
    solidgauge: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      linecap: 'round',
      rounded: true,
      stickyTracking: false
    }
  }
}
```

It is working in official [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-activity/) with same config setting.

but ReactHighcharts is not working.

[image: my highcharts]

Does anyone have a suggestion or can help ?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

**07/14 update**

code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts-more';
import SolidGauge from 'highcharts-solid-gauge';

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    HighchartsMore(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
    SolidGauge(ReactHighcharts.Highcharts);
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <ReactHighcharts config={
      multiChartsConfig(460,60,40,10,'Total','Sent')}></ReactHighcharts>
    );
  }
}

const multiChartsConfig = (value, open, click, placement, str1, str2) => {
  return {
    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        height: 180,
        width: 185,
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 0,
        style: { margin: 'auto' }
    },
    title: null,
    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: [
          {
            backgroundColor: '#D8D8D8',
            outerRadius: '110%',
            innerRadius: '100%',
            borderWidth: 0
          },{
            backgroundColor: '#D8D8D8',
            outerRadius: '93%',
            innerRadius: '83%',
            borderWidth: 0
          },{
            backgroundColor: '#D8D8D8',
            outerRadius: '76%',
            innerRadius: '66%',
            borderWidth: 0
          }
        ]
    },
    tooltip:     {
        enabled: false
    },
    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      lineWidth: 0,
      tickPositions: []
    },
    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        borderWidth: '34px',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          borderWidth: 0,
          y: -30,
          useHTML: true,
          formatter: () => {
            return (`
              <div style="text-align: center;font-size:15px;color: #777777;">
              <div style="color: #009fc5;font-size: 17px;">${value.toLocaleString()}</div><div>${str1}</div><div>${str2}</div>
              </div>
            `);
          }
        },
        linecap: 'round',
        rounded: true,
        stickyTracking: false
      }
    },
    credits:     {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'open',
        rounded: true,
        data: [{
          color: '#009fc5',
          radius: '110%',
          innerRadius: '100%',
          y: Math.round(open * 100) 
        }]
      },
      {
        name: 'click',
        data: [{
          color: 'green',
          radius: '93%',
          innerRadius: '83%',
          y: Math.round(click * 100) 
        }]
      },
      {
        name: 'placement',
        data: [{
          color: 'red',
          radius: '76%',
          innerRadius: '66%',
          y: Math.round(placement * 100) 
        }]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

Comment: Could you post more of your code? With most of it redacted it's hard to figure out if anything else is causing this.

Comment: It works for me. If you download highcharts package by npm default paths are different - https://jsfiddle.net/xtu0e60m/. How many times calls like HighchartsMore(React.Highcharts) are invoked? It should be done only once.

Comment: @WillHawker ok, updated :)

Comment: @morganfree I just call HighchartsMore(React.Highcharts) in constructor. so , it should once.

Comment: It shoudn't be placed in the constructor if the component is created multiple times (it will wrap already wrapped file and cause the issue). It should be called once per app, e.g. when you bootstrap the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is where you're getting the solid gauge extension from. The `highcharts-solid-gauge` package is massively out of date.

Use this instead

```
import SolidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge';
```

Version you're using (see https://npmcdn.com/highcharts-solid-gauge@latest) is v4.2.3

Where as the current version is v5.0.12 - https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js

If you go to the official JSFiddle example you referenced, and change the solid-gauge script src to `https://npmcdn.com/highcharts-solid-gauge@latest` you'll see the same problem you're having.